# Time Format Interpretation

Tags: html

Am not a developer. I was using www.videonot.es service for taking notes from video tutorial that was synced with play time. Now, the site is down, From the the backup I could see the following time details that are synced with my notes.

{"24": {"time": 1249.974566}

How do I interpret the time shown below in the format of hh:mm:ss ?

Comment: To make an educated guess it would really help to know how long the video is and a bit of a guess when in the video the note should appear. Without knowing any of that, my first guess is that it's seconds.

Comment: @Evert 1 . The video length is 00.23:38. My problem is dis contiguous time. For example it's like {"24": {"time": 1249.974566}
 "25": {"time": 1249.974566}
 "27": {"time": 1291.202571}
 "20": {"time": 956.910622}
 "21": {"time": 1084.745905}
 "22": {"time": 1224.338784}
 "23": {"time": 1236.68146}
 "1": {"time": 47.705469}

Comment: @DineshKalidassan. 23 minutes and 38 seconds 1418 seconds. So it definitely suggests that the times are all specified as seconds (with fractions)